# Regular expression generating language {$w: w$ contains at least three $1$s}

Tags: automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

I am learning automata. As an answer to following question in my textbook, I came up with this answer.

> Give regular expression generating language {$w: w$ contains at least three $1$s}

$0^*10^*10^*1(0^*1^*)^*$

Can someone suggest if my answer is correct?

Comment: It looks good to me.

Comment: Your answer is coorect. A slightly simpler expression would be $0^*10^*10^*1(0 \cup 1)^*$.